# Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph and had successfully set up the ability to create subscriptions and receive push notifications. However, the process of creating a subscription is no longer working and I am stumped.

```
2018-01-25T23:32:41.694741+00:00 app[web.1]: 
OData::ClientError (400 InvalidRequest: 
"Subscription validation request failed. 
Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter." 
from "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions"):
```

Code to return `validationToken` in response. When I curl, my response is exactly as it should be.

```
def outlook_subscription
  render plain: params[:validationToken]
  head 200 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed on our end. Since when did you start seeing this problem ? Did you deploy any new version of your (or the backed library) code ?

Please check the request/response in your logs and check if they both match (case sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

This work for me!

```
def outlook_subscription
  render json: params[:validationToken], content_type: "plain/text", status: 200 
end
```